# list of object Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Having trouble with an exercise from the Eloquent JavaScript book https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html. The task is to create a list out of an array. Actually I am having trouble understanding concept of list presented in this book. here is what is says.

> Objects, as generic blobs of values, can be used to build all sorts
>   of data structures. A common data structure is the list (not to be
>   confused with array). A list is a nested set of objects, with the
>   first object holding a reference to the second, the second to the
>   third, and so on.
>
> ```
> let list = {
>   value: 1,
>   rest: {
>     value: 2,
>     rest: {
>       value: 3,
>       rest: null
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> A nice thing about lists is that they can share parts of their
>   structure. For example, if I create two new values: `{value: 0, rest: list}` and `{value: -1, rest: list}` (with list referring to the binding
>   defined earlier), they are both independent lists, but they share the
>   structure that makes up their last three elements. The original list
>   is also still a valid three-element list.

I cannot understand how did he create two new values and how they are independent lists.
it will be very helpful if someone can provide good code example.i am just beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How did he create two new values?

Just creating two new variables and assigning a value to them:

```js
const list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};

const first = { value: 0, rest: list };
const second = { value: -1, rest: list };

console.log(first)
console.log(second)
```

> How they are independent lists?

These are just two different variables and each of theme has its own value - so that's why they're independent. In that case they can be called independent *lists*, because of the data structure they have. And also, they share the same structure from `list` variable. Which means, if we change something in `list` variable it will affect the part of `first` and `second` lists that holds reference to `list` variable. It also works vise-versa, if we change it in `first` or `second` it'll affect `list` as well.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create two arrays such as:

```
const a = [0];
const b = [-1];
```

These two arrays are independent of each other - `a` has been assigned its own instance of an array and `b` has also been assigned its own array instance. The same applies to objects (in-fact, arrays themselves are object). If you have two objects like so:

```
const a = {value: 0, rest: null};
const b = {value: -1, rest: null};
```

each variable has its own object-literal assigned to it. The standalone objects themselves act as their own independent lists.

In the example given in the book, you still have the same situation of having two independently created lists (as each object-literal represents a new list), however, the `rest` property has a value of a reference to another (3rd) `list`.

```
const a = {value: 0, rest: list};
const b = {value: -1, rest: list};
```

So `a` and `b` are their own list instances, however, they both have a reference which point to the same `list` object created earlier.